# Why does ostream_iterator need to explicitly declare the type of objects to output?

Tags: c++, stream

In current C++, the class ostream_iterator was designed like the following:

```
// excerpted from the standard C++

template<class T, ...>
class ostream_iterator
{
public:
    ostream_iterator(ostream_type&);
    ...

    ostream_iterator<T,...>& operator =(const T&);
    ...
};
```

To me, this design is suboptimal. Because the user must specify the type T when declaring an ostream_iterator like this: `ostream_iterator<int> oi(cout);` In fact, cout can take any type of object as its argument, rather than only one type. This is an obvious restriction.

```
// Below is my own version

// doesn't need any template parameter here
class ostream_iterator
{
public:
    ostream_iterator(ostream_type&);
    ...

    // define a template member function which can take any type of argument and output it
    template<class T> 
    ostream_iterator<T,...>& operator =(const T&);
    ...
};
```

Now, we can use it as follows:

```
ostream_iterator oi(cout);
```

I think it is more generic and more elegant than

```
ostream_iterator<int> oi(cout);
```

Am I right?

Comment: What's the `value_type` of your ostream_iterator?

Comment: @MSalters: It is not required that ostream_iterator class must typedef a nested value_type. So I think the type deduction can be delayed until when operator =() is called.

Comment: Pehaps I don't understand the problem your trying to solve. What algorithms are you going to use with your `ostream_iterator` that are going to generate objects of different types?  If you stream out objects of different types, how would you then be able to know the correct types to read them back in to?

Comment: @Charles Bailey: There are many tricks to tell the extractor what the next object's type is. For example, you can use an integer as type identifier to indicate the next object's type.

Comment: We don't need to care how the extractor will read the objects from the stream. Just as you write cout << 1 << "Hello"; you don't care how the extractor will read its contents.

Comment: @xmllmx, but what is the point of that when you are iterating over the contents of a container where *each entry* is of type `T`? btw. this is for *output* not for extracting from a stream...

Comment: I think you've better illustrated the point I'm trying to make. If you've passed your iterator to an algorithm, it's not going to give the opportunity to stop and put in your identifier. If you need finer grain control and are building up the output object at a time, why not just use a `std::ostream&` which already has a polymorphic output idiom: `operator<<` ?

Comment: &Nim: You are right. I'm off topic.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: We are discussing the design of ostream_iterator rather than how to use it. I think the latter is more generic and more elegant than the current design. Imagine we have an algorithm to output several types of objects to the ostream, the discussion would make sense.

Comment: What do you believe the design goal of `ostream_iterator` is, or should be? Because I believe that you are trying to solve a different problem to the class of problems that the standard one solves.

Comment: @xmllmx, that would require a container capable of holding more than one unrelated type (which none of the STL container are capable of - unless I've missed a trick somewhere...) The only container I could think of that can hold multiple types is a `boost::fusion` sequence, but again there, you'd stream out directly to the stream and take advantage of the `operator<<`

Comment: @Nim: use the latter version won't break the existing standard containers and algorithms, it will work in any case that the current version works. But the latter is more beautiful to me.

Comment: @Nim: That would NOT require a container capable of holding more than one unrelated type. That would SUPPORT a container capable of holding more than one unrelated type.

Comment: @MSalters: The `value_type` is `void` (it's an output iterator, 24.3.1/1)

Comment: OP is correct. I'm waiting for [make_ostream_joiner](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ostream_joiner/make_ostream_joiner) as of 2020.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you could be right.

Let's see if we can construct an ostream_iterator that does not need a template argument.

The iterator works by copying values into it, so `*iter = x; ++iter;`
The iterator cheats by making operator* return itself and `++iter` also returning itself without changing any state. The "magic" is in the operator= which performs the output.

The "cout" must be a class member of type ostream*. It needs to be a pointer as iterators must be assignable, thus we assign the member (call it os) to the address of the stream passed in.

So we would overload operator= this way:

```
template< typename T >
our_ostream_iterator& operator=( const T& t )
{
   (*os) << t;
   if( delim )
      (*os) << delim;
   return *this;
}
```

Note that the templatised operator= should not oveload operator=(our_ostream_iterator const&) which is more specialised than the template.

You would still want a template on the element type so we will call that `our_basic_ostream_iterator`

ostream_iterator would still remain a template class on its element type. Thus:

```
template< typename E, typename TR=char_traits<E> >
class our_basic_ostream_iterator : public std::iterator< /*traits here*/ >
{
public:
   typedef E element_type;
   typedef TR traits_type;
   typedef basic_ostream< E, TR > stream_type;
private:
   stream_type * os;
   const E* delim;
public:
   our_basic_ostream_iterator( stream_type s, const E* d = nullptr ) :
      os( &s ), delim( d )
   {
   }

   our_basic_ostream_iterator& operator++() { return *this; }
   our_basic_ostream_iterator operator++(int) { return *this; }
   our_basic_ostream_iterator& operator*() { return *this; }

   template< typename T >
   our_basic_ostream_iterator& operator=( const T& t ); // as above
};
```

and then of course

```
typedef our_basic_ostream_iterator<char> our_ostream_iterator;
typedef our_basic_ostream_iterator<wchar_t> our_wostream_iterator;
```

The drawback of all of this though is that the above does not conform to all the properties of iterators such that it could be passed to any algorithm / class that requires a forward iterator. Why? Because such an algorithm should be able to invoke iterator_traits to extract the element type and the class above does not contain an element type.

It would lead to compile-time errors in the algorithm that is using your iterator and would potentially be hard to track down the reason why.

Comment: This still has to be used as `our_ostream_iterator<something>`, though, which is what the questioner wants to avoid. To have a chance of using it without naming its type, you also need some kind of wrapper function which will deduce the template arguments (and then C++0x `auto` and `decltype` mean you never need to use the type, while in C++03 you sometimes still need to spell it out).

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP needs to deduce element type and wide input/output from the constructor but you could use a function to deduce what type to make and use that, dependent on what stream you passed in.

Comment: You pass `stream_type s` by value and save its address into `os`.

Comment: This answer claims to "construct an ostream_iterator that does not need a template argument.", but clearly has `typename E` in its definition of `our_basic_ostream_iterator`. How is this correct?

Comment: OP meant the type being streamed. The template parameter in my code is that of the element-type i.e. whether it is char or wchar_t and you can typedef it because you now can. The character type though should be derivable from the stream object you could use auto make_ostream_iterator(...),

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that `iterator` have associated types and `ostream_iterator` conceptually violates the concept of an iterator by requiring a `value_type` even when it is not necessary. (This is basically @pts's answer)

What you are proposing is related to the idea behind the new "transparent operators", such as the new `std::plus<void>`. Which consist in having a special instantiation whose member function has a delayed type deduction.

It is also backward compatible because `void` is not a useful instantiation to begin with. Moreover the `void` parameter is also the default. For example `template<T = void> struct std::plus{...}` is the new declaration.

---

**A possible implementation of a transparent `ostream_iterator`**

Going back of `std::ostream_iterator`, an important test is whether we want to make it work with `std::copy` as `std::ostream_iterator` is usually used:

```
std::vector<int> v = {...};
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

The technology for a transparent `std::ostream_iterator` is not there yet, because this fails:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<void>(std::cout, " "));
```

To make this work, one can explicitly define the `void` instance. (This completes @CashCow 's answer)

```
#include<iterator>
namespace std{
    template<>
    struct ostream_iterator<void> : 
        std::iterator<std::output_iterator_tag, void, void, void, void>
    {
        ostream_iterator(std::ostream& os, std::string delim) : 
            os_(os), delim_(delim)
        {}
        std::ostream& os_;
        std::string delim_;
        template<class T> ostream_iterator& operator=(T const& t){
            os_ << t << delim_;
            return *this;
        }
        ostream_iterator& operator*(){return *this;}
        ostream_iterator& operator++(){return *this;}
        ostream_iterator& operator++(int){return *this;}
    };

}
```

Now this works:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<void>(std::cout, " "));
```

Moreover, if we convince the standard committee to have a default `void` parameter (as they did with with `std::plus`): 
`template<class T = void, ...> struct ostream_iterator{...}`, we could go a step further and omit the parameter altogether:

```
std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<>(std::cout, " "));
```

---

**The root of the problem and a possible way out**

Finally, in my opinion the problem might also be conceptual, in STL one expects an iterator to have a definite `value_type` associated even if it is not necessary like here. In some sense `ostream_iterator` violates some concepts of what is an iterator.

So there are two things that are conceptually wrong in this usage: 1) when one copies one expects to know the type of the source (container `value_type`) and target types 2) one is not copying anything in the first place!. In my opinion there is a double design mistake in this typical usage. There should be a `std::send` that works with a template shift `<<` operators directly, instead of making `=` redirect to `<<` as `ostream_iterator` does.

```
std::send(v.begin(), v.end(), std::cout); // hypothetical syntax
std::send(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_receiver(std::cout, " ")); // hypothetical syntax
std::send(v.begin(), v.end(), 'some ostream_filter'); // hypothetical syntax
```

(The last argument should fulfill some kind of `Sink` concept).

---

** Using `std::accumulate` instead and a possible implementation of 
`std::send` **

From a conceptual point of view, sending objects to a stream is more of an "accumulate" operation than a copy operator, so in principle `std::accumulate` should be a more suitable candidate, besides we don't need "target" iterators for it. 
The problem is that `std::accumulate` wants to make copies of every object that is being accumulated, so this doesn't work:

```
    std::accumulate(e.begin(), e.end(), std::cout, 
        [](auto& sink, auto const& e){return sink << e;}
    ); // error std::cout is not copiable
```

To make it work we need to do some `reference_wrapper` magic:

```
    std::accumulate(e.begin(), e.end(), std::ref(std::cout), 
        [](auto& sink, auto const& e){return std::ref(sink.get() << e);}
    );
```

Finally, the code can be simplified by having the equivalent of `std::plus` for the shift operator, in modern C++ this should look like this IM:

```
namespace std{

    template<class Sink = void, class T = void>
    struct put_to{
        std::string delim_;
        using sink_type = Sink;
        using input_type = T;
        Sink& operator()(Sink& s, T const& t) const{
            return s << t << delim_;
        }
    };

    template<>
    struct put_to<void, void>{
        std::string delim_;
        template<class Sink, class T>
        Sink& operator()(Sink& s, T const& t){
            return s << t;
        }
        template<class Sink, class T>
        std::reference_wrapper<Sink> operator()(std::reference_wrapper<Sink> s, T const& t){
            return s.get() << t << delim_;
        }
    };

}
```

Which can be used as:

```
std::accumulate(e.begin(), e.end(), std::ref(std::cout), std::put_to<>{", "});
```

Finally we can define:

```
namespace std{
    template<class InputIterator, class Sink>
    Sink& send(InputIterator it1, InputIterator it2, Sink& s, std::string delim = ""){
        return std::accumulate(it1, it2, std::ref(s), std::put_to<>{delim});
    }
}
```

Which can be used as

```
std::send(e.begin(), e.end(), std::cout, ", ");
```

Finally, there is no dilemma about the type of any `output_iterator` here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason is that it has other members also. Obviously the entire set of member functions need to be consistent in their behavior for a given set of T and other template arguments.

There's danger in `operator <` being instantiated for a set of template arguments which is different from what is used to instantiate `operator *` or `operator++`

Hence, the individual methods are not template themselves and rather the entire class is a template so ensure uniform T and other template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It would be more flexible as you suggest. However, the way it's designed fits more closely to how STL uses iterators: one iterator type for data type (T).